# ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() functions not getting fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a Q/A website. When the user clicks on a particular question, he is redirected to the question page where the user can post answers.

Now, the issue is while the user clicks on "Answer" link, few things are processing in the background like updating db, sending mail, etc. I am trying to display a load indicator in the UI but the AJAX function is not getting triggered.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<span id="msg"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"/></span>
<a id="sub-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadAnswerList(document.getElementById('user-ans').value,<?php echo $qid; ?>,'<?php echo $posted_by; ?>')">Answer</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#msg').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#msg').hide();
});
```

AJAX request

```
function loadAnswerList(ans,qid,postedBy,page)  {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ans_container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","load_answers.php?ans="+ans+"&qid="+qid+"&postedBy="+postedBy+"&page="+page,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I also tried adding $(document).ready(function()  { .... }); above the ajax but still it is not working. Am I missing anything?

Am using jQuery version 3.2.1

Comment: Can you please add your AJAX code to the question too

Comment: Thanks. added. Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: because that Ajax call ain't jQuery's Ajax call. If you want to use before and after, than use jQuery's Ajax methods.

Comment: @epascarello - Can u please elaborate. Am a beginner. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not work with the native XMLHttpRequest object. The ajaxStart and ajaxEnd lines you are using deals with their api. So in order to use it, you need to use jQuery's [`.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the details.
This is the modified function:

```
function loadAnswerList(ans,qid,postedBy,page)  {
var answer=ans;
var qstnid=qid;
var postby=postedBy;
var pg=page;

var request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "load_answers.php?ans="+ans+"&qid="+qid+"&postedBy="+postedBy+"&page="+page",
    data: {ans: answer, qid: qstn_id, postedBy: postby, page: pg},
    dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  alert ( "Response: " + msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

}
```

Please correct me if am wrong. One more thing - I want to display the response from the php page to a particular div as I have done in my previous ajax request.

```
document.getElementById("ans_container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

How do I do it here?